# Proving a Floor Function is Onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that the function $f(x) = \lfloor 4 \sqrt{x} \rfloor$ is onto, but I can't figure out how to prove it. The function is from $\mathbf{Q^+} \cup \{0\} \to \mathbf{N}$. I can't figure out how to move the floor parts around in order to solve for $a$ in terms of $f(a)$ (where $a$ is some arbitrary number in the domain).

Answer (score 2):

$f\left({{n^2}\over {16}}\right)=n$

Answer (score 2):

We wish to prove that every $n$ is in the range of $f(x)$. To do this, simply take $x = \frac{n^2}{16}$.